# Convert string to epoch timestamp

Tags: python

I have timestamps in the following format:

```
date = Fri Nov 30 13:32:45 UTC 2012
```

Is there a way to convert this string to an epoch timestamp? I haven't been able to figure out how to convert this string? Here's what I have been trying:

```
import datetime

d = 'Fri Nov 30 13:32:45 UTC 2012'
fmt = '%a %b %e %R %Y'
print d.strftime(fmt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the timezone directive:

> **%Z** Time zone name (no characters if no time zone exists).

You used the wrong "day of the month" directive:

> **%d** Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].

You used the wrong "time" directive:

> **%X** Locale’s appropriate time representation.

Try:

```
>>> import time
>>> d = 'Fri Nov 30 13:32:45 UTC 2012'
>>> fmt = '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y'
>>> epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d, fmt)))
>>> print epoch
1354278765
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still getting this error with your suggestions: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: @turtle It's not `strftime()` (`f` = format), it's `strptime()` (`p` = parse).

Answer (score 0):

You need `strptime` method of class `datetime`. And the format you need is `%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y`. With your example it give :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = "Fri Nov 30 13:32:45 UTC 2012"
>>> fmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, fmt)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 30, 13, 32, 45)
>>> d.timestamp()
1354278765.0
```